# Restoring a note

Tags: ubuntu-one, tomboy, notes

Is it possible to restore a deleted note in Ubuntu One? On the web page "Recent activities" it says "TODO deleted"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible.  I read about in the [ubuntu-bugs mail archive](http://www.mail-archive.com/ubuntu-bugs@lists.ubuntu.com/msg2791906.html)   .

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot - I have now recovered my never ending TODO list :)

Answer (score 3):

The [complete procedure](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntuone-client/+bug/730951/comments/3):

1. [Download Script](http://people.canonical.com/~roman.yepishev/us/ubuntuone-couchdb-undelete.py)
2. Find all deleted notes:

   ```
   python ./ubuntuone-couchdb-undelete.py --dry-run notes
   ```
3. Restore note (Example: "31d3caac-6b5c-47ce-8edb-4cb74a8b34a2")

   ```
   python ./ubuntuone-couchdb-undelete.py notes 31d3caac-6b5c-47ce-8edb-4cb74a8b34a2
   ```

Answer (score 1):

The possible solution that Renat mentions looks promising.  The mail-archive broke the URL of the script described, but you can also see these instructions in the [original bug entry in launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntuone-client/+bug/730951) for more details.

Here's an excerpt:

> [...] please contact ubuntuone-...@canonical.com
>   so that we can help you recover your note in
>   case the instructions below are not
>   helpful
>
> Please download the script from
>   http://people.canonical.com/~roman.yepishev/us/ubuntuone-couchdb-undelete.py and run it in the terminal
>   as described below:
>
> Find all deleted notes:
>
> ```
> $ python ./ubuntuone-couchdb-undelete.py --dry-run notes
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Got this error message

```
ERROR: Access token cannot be found. I tried
Ubuntu SSO and gnomekeyring and found nothing

Please authorize your machine via Tomboy or Ubuntu One.
```

Answer (score 0):

The script mentioned in other answers doesn't work anymore as @Jaseem points out.

All your deleted notes should be backed up in `~/.local/share/tomboy/` and `~/.local/share/tomboy/Backup/`.

```
find ~/.local/share/tomboy/ -name '*.note'
```

The problem is that notes are only backed up here if you've edited them on this box.

However if you can remember the last machine you edited them on then you can copy them from there.

(Ubuntu 12.04 just crashed on me and took all open tomboy notes with it (wtf), but this works for me in 12.04 with Tomboy 1.10.1)

Comment: Additionally I'm now unable to sync the notes =(